# hide status link on mouseover(with example) HOW?

Tags: php, javascript, url, hide, status

*Since Nobody knows, taken off the question.*

Comment: Can you clarify what it is you want to do, without linking to an example?  I went there, but still have no idea what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm sorry, but after reading this three times I still cannot understand what are you trying to ask here. Can you please explain yourself more clearly? You can edit your question at any time with the **edit** button you see below the tags

Comment: have updated. if still not clear, let me know. thanks a million guys

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know exactly how the redirect is done i think you might have been tricked as there are two iframes. One is directly over the the entire page(width & height = 1000 with src="ads.php"|) and another one follows the mouse.
I think this might interest you:
<td align="center" valign="middle" onclick="ga(this,event)" onmouseout="cs()" onmouseover="return ss('go to www.GrameenFoundation.org','aw0')" onmousedown="st('aw0')" onfocus="ss('go to www.GrameenFoundation.org','aw0')" class="ch" id="taw0">...</td>

Comment: sorry, doesnt quite catch you fully there.. i understand there is 1 over the entire page and another follows the mouse. what i don't understand is why is it not showing the link url that is underneath the mouse all the time. Are you saying that ads.php is on top of the one that follows the mouse? thereby making the link not displaying on the window status?   i don't quite get the coding.. is it taken from the website above? thanks in advance.